# How do I find if an edge exists between X and Y using prolog?

Tags: prolog, graph-theory

I'm having difficulty determining if edges exist between two points, X and Y. My graph looks like this:

```
edge(a, c, 2). 
edge(b, e, 2).
edge(d, e, 1).
edge(c, d, 2).
edge(a, b, 2). 
edge(a, d, 3).
edge(b, a, 1).
edge(a, a, 2).
```

I have made the following attempt among many other scenarios

```
connected(X,Y):- 
  edge(X,Y,_).
connected(X,Y):-
  edge(X,Z,_),
  connected(Z,Y).
```

...however everything keeps returning true, even when I put in obviously bad data that should return false. Here are some examples:

```
188 ?- connected(a,c).
true .

189 ?- connected(a,x).
true .

190 ?- connected(b,x).
true .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your first clause `connected(X, Y)` says that any pair of terms is connected. Remove it. The rest looks OK.

Edit: "Looks OK" is relative: Your graph has cycles and thus an infinite number of paths. You will therefore always get non-termination on queries for non-existent paths like `connected(a, x)`. If you want to get a failure on these, you will have to change your definition to keep a list of visited nodes to avoid visiting them again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I took out the first line and ended up getting this: ERROR: >=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated. So I took out the L >= 0 as well, and I'm back to the same problem with everything coming back true.

Comment: That error is impossible if you always have an `edge/3` call that binds `L` before the `>=` comparison. The code you are using must be different from the code above. Please edit your post to add the actual code you are using for this.

Comment: Possibly the first clause should have been `connected(X,X).`